# R Combine use of new readr/vroom lazy loading + dplyr AND dtplyr/data.table?

Tags: r, dplyr, readr, dtplyr, vroom

I am loading a large dataset that I need to filter approximately 1/20th of the rows and then group_by by 5 columns and summarize 3 remaining ones.

This page https://vroom.r-lib.org/articles/benchmarks.html
says sampling, filtering, and grouped aggregation are much faster due to the lazy altrep implementation.

Since "Once a particular vector is fully materialized the speed for all subsequent operations should be identical to a normal R vector." my question is if it makes sense that it could still be advantageous to use dtplyr or data.table for the summarize operation, after filtering?

Comment: data.table or dtplyr as opposed to what? What do you want to compare?

Comment: I am trying to determine whether it is advantageous to do filter, group_by, and summarize within a lazily loaded vroom/readr data frame, or whether to use dtplyr or data.table to do the filter, group_by, and summarize / aggregate on loaded/materialized data frames.